# Is it possible to create CampaignInfluence records via apex?

Tags: campaign, campaign-member, campaign-influence

As per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaigninfluence.htm this documentation salesforce has started exposing CampaignInfluence object.

But when I tried to access it in Apex, I am getting invalid type CampaignInfluence.

I have enabled the campaign influence but even then I was getting the error.

Is it possible to create CampaignInfluence records in apex?

Comment: Check the API version on your Apex class. It must be at least v37.0 or later to access CampaignInfluence. I don't have "Campaign Influence" enabled, so I can't test it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too and as Daniel mentioned in the comments, updating the API version of your Apex class, to 37.0 or higher, does resolve this.

Confirmed in [these docs.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaigninfluencemodel.htm)

Comment: Really odd. In the dev console query editor I get an unsupported object message. I created a class to do the same and now it works. Thanks for the tip!